# Difference between Synchronized static method and a synchronized block inside a static method?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

While implementing the Singleton pattern, could someone please explain the difference between:

Synchronized Static Method:

```
    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance==null){
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

and Synchronized block inside a static method:

```
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance==null){
            synchronized(Singleton.class){
                if(instance==null){
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

Why do we have to check `instance==null` twice in the second method and what is the advantage of the second method over the first?

Comment: Word of advice: don't implement a Singleton this way, use [an enum](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3) (if you *really* need a Singleton...)

Answer (score 1):

In the second example you have to check `instance==null` twice because of race conditions - if two threads check this condition at the same time then both of them go further with the `if` statement. Then only one can enter into the critical section, but without `null` check again `thread2` would override the value of `instance`

The difference is that the first one is `coarse grained` synchronization and the second one is `fine grained`:

- in the first example you will obtain lock every time you call the function (it's slower)
- in the second one you will probably obtain the lock only on the first function call (much faster due to not locking every time)

Comment: One important detail is missing from your explanation: [this idiom is broken and dangerous...](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html)

Comment: I would not say "coarse-grained" and "fine-grained" here.  Those terms usually refer to the number of locks used in a complex data structure.  If every record in the structure has its own lock, and different threads can operate on different records at the same time, then that's the extreme of what people usually call that "fine-grained" locking.   The opposite extreme, "coarse-grained locking", would be where one lock protects everything, and only one thread at a time can access anything.

Comment: @jameslarge so can't these terms be applied here as well? In the first case only one thread can access to the method in the second one multiple thread can access.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "access the method".  The purpose of the locking in this case is to insure that two different threads don't end up using two different instances of the `Singleton` class.  Both examples achieve that, but the second example has a flaw (see kryger's "broken and dangerous" link).